# How to get the Value of an EditText (Layout.xml) on public interface?

Tags: java, android, api, android-studio, interface

I'm still learning Android Programming and I need help...
I create (from online tutorial) Weather App using Retrofit and Yahoo Weather API.
But this App is made just for one specific City.
Now I would like to Add two EditText (City, Country) and put those content into API link.

I've made activity_settings.xml

```
<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/etCity"
    android:text="Zagreb"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />
```

and WeatherAPI.java

```
public interface WeatherAPI{

String BASE_URL = "https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/";
//String Zagreb = "Zagreb";
EditText cityText = (EditText) findViewById (R.id.etCity);
String city = cityText.getText().toString();


@GET("yql?q=select%20*%20from%20weather.forecast%20where%20woeid%20in%20(select%20woeid%20from%20geo.places(1)%20where%20text%3D%22" + city + "%2C%20Hr%22)%20and%20u%3D'c'&format=json&env=store%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltableswithkeys")
Call<Weather> getWeather();

class Factory {

    public static WeatherAPI service;

    public static WeatherAPI getIstance() {

        if (service == null) {

            Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder().addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                    .build();


            service = retrofit.create(WeatherAPI.class);
            return service;
        } else {
            return service;
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see I've add

```
EditText cityText = (EditText) findViewById (R.id.etCity);
String city = cityText.getText().toString();
```

and put city into `@GET("......")`

I get errors:

> Error:(20, 42) error: cannot find symbol method findViewById(int)
>   Error:(24, 145) error: attribute value must be constant

Comment: You can not get text immediately after creating object of Edittext. it will be always blank

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calling `findViewById()` on the Activity object will only work if the current Activity layout is set by **setContentView**. If you add a layout through some other means, then you need the View object of the layout and call `findViewById()` on it.

like this..

```
View v = inflater.inflate(id_layout);
View innerView = v.findViewById(R.id.etCity);
```

Comment: Thank you, only thing that I don't understand is: does I need to add View v = inflater.inflate(id_layout);..... on MainActivity.java or WeatherAPI.java?

Answer (score 1):

What my friend here tried to say, is that as long as you are outside the VIEW object you can call `findViewById()` easily, however once you are inside that element and you are looking for the `findViewById()` you need to write before the VIEW object before like this:

```
Context.findViewById ()
```

or in your case

```
WeatherAPI.findViewById ()
```